# Winforms MVP-VM Pattern - How to limit functionality when logged out

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms

**Background**

I'm creating a windows forms application that implements the MVP-VM pattern. This post explains the overall approach I'm taking:
http://aviadezra.blogspot.ca/2009/08/mvp-mvvm-winforms-data-binding.html

My application has a main window that opens on application start-up. The main contents of the application are hidden until the user logs in, after which the user controls which expose application functionality are revealed.

The main window has multiple presenters, each one representing a different set of logically grouped functionality. When the application starts, only the presenter that creates the login dialog is populated. Then, once the user logs in, the remaining presenters are created. I feel this is a good way to prevent users from somehow accessing functionality until they are logged in.

**Question**

When a user logs out, I'm having trouble deciding what needs to be done. I don't want to re-create the main window, but the state of the main window at login is I think what I'm trying to achieve (only the one presenter initialized). When someone logs out, should I dispose all presenters except for the one that creates the login screen? How do I do that? I don't imagine just setting the presenters in the main form to null would work, eh?

Comment: You really should show us your code. Nevertheless, the point of the VM is to provide the UI with all of the binding information so it should understand about being logged in or not and present to the UI the right details so that you don't need to dispose anything. Then you can properly test that your app behaves when logged out. There shouldn't be any "somehow accessing functionality" if you've created suitable unit tests.

Comment: The blog post shows code that I'm aiming to model mine after. I can't say I really understand what you mean when you say the VM provides all the information required. My view models (and similarly with the blog post I linked) are simple data objects (largely without behaviour) that get populated via a call to a MT service. The service will definitely require a valid login before providing back requested data, but what about data that's already bound to the UI when the logout occurs. Shouldn't I go about clearing that data/binding?

Comment: The VM should automatically react to any change in the model - including being logged in or not - so then the UI can be up-to-date 100% of the time. This is the whole point of databinding and MVVM-type architectures. You shouldn't have to go about clearing anything. The VM should automatically do it for you based on changes to your model (which includes the logged in status).

Comment: Sorry, still not grabbing what you're saying. That articles shows a model as essentially being a service (i.e. with a GetAllCustomers() method). The presenter makes a call to the model/service to get data. That data is then saved into the VM (the reference to that VM is stored in the presenter). Because the view is bound to the VM, the view/UI is automatically updated. I don't understand how the VM behind some grid it supposed to be updated because a login VM somewhere else changed. Could you maybe give an example? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure how the VM behind the grid **isn't** updated when the login data changes. You should need to pass some sort of reference to the login to each VM. When the login changes then each VM can update their UI. So a single VM may contain multiple model objects.

Comment: And, from the article, "The Model is a bunch of business objects that can include data and behaviors such as querying and updating the DB and interacting with external services. Such objects that only contain data are referred to as ‘data entities’." I think you're missing the point about the models - they are data objects. So you would pass all the data (models) to the VM that the VM needs. It's not a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: Hmmm, I see. So if I pass a reference to the login to each VM, how do you get a VM to react to changes in the login? Would that be some sort of event or something? Thank you for all the response, btw. Greatly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you should have all models implementing `INotifyPropertyChanged` which gives you the events you need.